# Generics on KProperty1.getDelegate too restrictive?

Tags: generics, reflection, kotlin

I am trying to obtain all property delegates of a certain type in a class hierarchy. This is presenting me with some issues.
For a start, there seems to be no straightforward way to obtain a class' superclass in Kotlin. The first way I tried was to use Java's `Class.getSuperclass`:

```
private fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.getSuperclass(): KClass<in T>? = (java.superclass as? Class<out Any>)?.kotlin as KClass<in T>
```

But this requires an unchecked cast, because Kotlin will not allow me to convert a `Class<in T>` back to Kotlin, because apparently in T means it could be something that is not Any, whatever that might be ("Type parameter has an upper bound 'Any' that cannot be satisfied capturing 'in' projection").

So I tried a pure Kotlin solution: First get all superclasses including interfaces (`KClass.superclasses`) and then filter out every interface. But there is nothing on `KClass` that tells me if it's an interface! So I have to go to Java for that again. And it again requires an unchecked cast, because for some reason `KClass.superclasses` is of type `List<KClass<*>>` and not `List<KClass<in T>>`:

```
private fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.getSuperclass123(): KClass<in T>? = superclasses.firstOrNull { it.java.isInterface } as KClass<in T>?
```

Am I missing something here? I must be.

Now for the actual question, trying to obtain all property delegate instances in a class hierarchy. First I wrote a function to obtain the instances for one class:

```
private fun <T : Any> KClass<T>.getProperties(obj: T) =
    declaredMemberProperties.also { it.forEach { it.isAccessible = true } }.asSequence().filter { it.getDelegate(obj) is MyPropertyDelegate }
```

Works fine. But of course I also need all the properties declared in superclasses. So naturally I tried to change the receiver to `KClass<in T>` which of course results in me not being able to call `declaredMemberProperties` anymore. How do I solve this?

I already tried using `KClass.memberProperties`, but it falls short if a subclass overrides a property which is delegated in a parent class. In that case it will only list the overridden property, which does not allow me to access the property delegate instance.

**Edit:**
I did some more testing, and the following Java code compiles just fine, as I would expect:

```
static <T> List<MyProperty> getProperties(KClass<? super T> clazz, T obj) {
    return KClasses.getDeclaredMemberProperties(clazz).stream()
            .map(p -> p.getDelegate(obj))
            .filter(MyProperty.class::isInstance)
            .map(MyProperty.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

What would be the equivalent Kotlin code?

**Edit²:**
Same for the super-class stuff. The following (albeit still ugly workaround) compiles in Java, but not in Kotlin (leaving out null-check here):

```
static <T> KClass<? super T> getSuperClass(KClass<T> clazz) {
    return JvmClassMappingKt.getKotlinClass(JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass(clazz).getSuperclass());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin your `getProperties()` will probably look like this:

```
inline fun <reified T:Any> T.getProperties(): List<MyProperty> = T::class.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence()
        .map { it.getDelegate(this) }
        .filter(MyProperty::class::isInstance)
        .map(MyProperty::class::safeCast)
        .filterNotNull() 
        .distinct()
        .toList()
```

And kotlin really don't have built in support for checking if a `KClass` represents an interface, which is really an awkward thing. Anyway, we have a workaround:

```
val KClass<*>.isInterface: Boolean
    get() = constructors.isEmpty()
```

This is an extension property for arbitrary `KClass`, testing if it represents an interface. This is based on the principle that classes, be it abstract, open, inner or final, must have at least one constructor, while interface can't have any constructors at all. However, filtering interfaces away isn't a good idea, because in kotlin an [interface can also have properties](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces).

Combining all the ideas above, we come to such result:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.getProperties(): List<MyProperty> = T::class.allSuperclasses.asSequence()
        .flatMap { it.declaredMemberProperties.asSequence() }
        .map { @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (it as KProperty1<in T, *>).getDelegate(this) }
        .filter(MyProperty::class::isInstance)
        .map(MyProperty::class::safeCast)
        .filterNotNull()
        .distinct()
        .toList()
```

The werid unchecked cast is a workaround for the `allClasses` declaration. I didn't study its implementation too much so I don't know if it's a technical constrain or laziness of a tired programmer, but that star projection forced me to use an unchecked cast. We all know it will be safe though.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. The isInterface is a nice trick. And I know interfaces can have properties, they can't be delegated properties though, so I do not need to worry about them and allSuperclasses specifically states that there is no particular order to them. I however need them in some defined order.
And while yes your answer does provide a solution, it doesn't answer why there is this constraint of not being able to call `declaredMemberProperties` on a `KClass<in T>`.
Oh, and you also have not answered how to get the actual superclass.